# Question about discrete mathematics: Show that if A and B are sets, then

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would I go about solving b? I am lost on how to do it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4SSw.png

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The problem may be attacked by **elbow grease**.  Take out a piece of scratch paper, and examine the assertion, as each expression goes from $(1)$ to $(n)$, rather than $(1)$ to $(+\infty)$.  Then, manually examine the cases of each value of $(n)$ in $\{3,5,10,100,1000\}$.  Then, look for a pattern in the data.  Then, try to stretch your intuition around what happens, as $n$ goes to $+\infty.$

Comment: Re my previous comment, please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.